# How to show fancybox window at 100% height?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

How to show fancybox window at 100% height depending on the contents?
I tried option `'height':'100%'`, but this show only window at border current window size.

Comment: `height:'100%'` relative to what? the parent container? the body, the viewport?

Comment: Parent container! For example, Now there is a block with height 400px and content inside with a 600px, but display only 400px. I need display parent fancyBox window at 600px(auto height)